# transfer single table data from one Database to other database with same table name?

Tags: sql

How can i transfer single table data from one Database to other database with same table name?

I have a database with data and other one has no data. 
They are not exactly the same as but one table is the same

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to export a table. Some are,

1. Using SELECT INTO Query

   Select * into Database1.Department from Database2.Department
2. Using SQL Server Export / Import wizard

   a. From SQL Server Management Studio, right-click on the database name in the object explorer, then choose Tasks -> Export Data

   b. Choose a Data Source and Destination

   c. Select the source table and follow the steps and execute the package

For more info, check http://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server/

Edited Note:
The above methods are for Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: How do you know Mandy is using SQL Server?